# How to convert 1s and 0s to String?

Tags: java, binary, arrays, byte

Please have a look at the following machine code

‎0111001101110100011100100110010101110011011100110110010101100100

This means something. I need to convert this to string. When I use Integer.parseInt() with the above as the string and 2 as the radix(to convert it to bytes), it gives number format exception.

And I believe I have to seperate this into sets of 8 pieces (like ‎01110011 , 10111010, etc). Am I correct?

Please help me to convert this correctly to string.

Thanks

Comment: If this is a binary representation of a series of bytes, you need to specify a character set to convert it into text.  Or do you just want the number?

Comment: You know what character encoding it is?

Comment: Is this just a number written in binary or random string data with unknown encoding?

Comment: I don't know what this is. It is a message sent to my FB account from one of my friends. He don't just send messages unless otherwise there is a meaning.

Comment: It you just need to convert that one piece of data (instead of actually programming anything), use something like [this converter](http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/Binary_To_Text.asp). The binary you posted is ASCII for "stressed".

Comment: Thats a nice find Jonik. But,when I pass it, it doesnt give me anything, why is that? I even divided it into sets of 8 pieces

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot for the comment. 

Can someone please tell me how to convert it to ascii manually? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter way of reading large integers is to use BigInteger

```
final String s = "0111001101110100011100100110010101110011011100110110010101100100";
System.out.println(new String(new BigInteger('0'+s, 2).toByteArray(), 0));
```

prints

```
stressed
```

Comment: Simpler, indeed :) Uses more memory, though, but that won't matter for anything less that a million chars.

Answer (score 11):

```
final String s = 
  "0111001101110100011100100110010101110011011100110110010101100100";
final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i+=8) 
  b.append((char)Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i,i+8),2));
System.out.println(b);
```

prints "stressed"

Comment: Using BigInteger is much simpler ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. If I am allowed to mark 2 best answers, I will mark this as an answer too. I am glad to see two ways of converting these!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the encoding of the String.

An ASCII coded string uses 1 byte for each character while a unicode coded string takes 2 bytes for each character. There are many other types of encodings. The binary layout differs for each encoding.

So you need to find the encoding that was used to write this string to binary format

Comment: Unicode is not an encoding and only one encoding scheme of unicode always takes 2 bytes for a character.